# Application of double integrals problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

The centroid of a uniform plane region is at $(0,0)$ and the region has total mass $m$. Show that its moment of inertia about an axis perpendicular to the $xy$-plane at the point ($x_0$,$y_0$) is $I=I_0+m(x_o^2+y_0^2)$.

Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Parallel axis theorem, also known as Steiner's Rule. You can read up on it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem